# Differentiate a conditional expected value by its probability

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm working on a problem for my thesis and I need to differentiate the conditional expected value by either the probability or the cutoff value for the conditional (whichever is easiest, though I suspect the probability).

Specifically, I have:

$$\mathbb{E} \left( x | x > a \right) = \frac{ \int_a^{\infty} x f\left(x\right) dx }{ \int_a^{\infty} f\left(x\right) dx }\equiv \tilde{x}$$ and $$Pr \left (x> a\right) =  \int_a^{\infty} f\left(x\right) dx\equiv \alpha$$

I want either an expression for $\frac{\partial \tilde{x} }{\partial \alpha}$, or $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial a}$ and $\frac{\partial \alpha} {\partial a}$.

I would prefer not to assume a particular distribution

The first is preferable as I can then solve my entire model in terms of $\alpha$.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use Leibntz rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
The problem becomes trivial

Comment: Your expression for the conditional expectation is incorrect. Note that you need the conditional distribution in this expression, which is equal to the original one divided by $\alpha$. The rest should follow afterwards. You should get $\frac{\partial\tilde x}{\partial\alpha} = -\frac{1}{\alpha}\tilde{x}$.

Comment: Marc - thanks, you're correct. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you intend those partial derivatives to be interpreted, since as far as I can tell there's only a single independent variable.

$$
\def\dd#1#2{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}\dd{\tilde x}\alpha=\dd{\tilde x}a\dd a\alpha=\left(\frac{af(a)}{\alpha}-\frac{\tilde xf(a)}{\alpha}\right)f(a)^{-1}=\frac{a-\tilde x}{\alpha}\;.
$$

Comment: The partials get used in my broader model. The model is then solved in terms of the $\alpha$ (the agent chooses $\alpha$ to maximize their payoff).

Comment: @James: Then you need to indicate what's being held constant. Using partial derivatives in a setting where it's not implicitly clear what variables are being held constant is meaningless and often leads to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The model can either be solved in terms of the $\alpha$ or $a$. Choosing one fixes the other. The $a$ in this case is the bid price in an auction, while the $\alpha$ is the probability the bid price is accepted.