# How partial derivatives in this answer were calculated, and how to understand a notation in the answer

Tags: integration, derivatives

There is a question asking how to calculate $\frac{\partial \tilde{x}}{\partial a}$, where $\tilde{x}$ is defined as follows.

$$\mathbb{E} \left( x | x > a \right) = \frac{ \int_a^{\infty} x f\left(x\right) dx }{ \int_a^{\infty} f\left(x\right) dx }\equiv \tilde{x}$$ and $$Pr \left (x> a\right) =  \int_a^{\infty} f\left(x\right) dx\equiv \alpha$$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780921) states that the answer is as follows

$$
\def\dd#1#2{\frac{\mathrm d#1}{\mathrm d#2}}\dd{\tilde x}\alpha=\dd{\tilde x}a\dd a\alpha=\left(\frac{af(a)}{\alpha}-\frac{\tilde xf(a)}{\alpha}\right)f(a)^{-1}=\frac{a-\tilde x}{\alpha}\;.
$$

My questions are

> What is the meaning/interpretation of $\frac{da}{d\alpha}$. **Isn't $a$ just a constant?**
>
> How was this partial derivative actually calculated? I believe it is just Leibniz rule, but do I combine Liebniz rule with the quotient rule? An example of What I have in Mind is below

---

I believe Leibniz rule on the numerator would be

$$
\frac{d\tilde{x}}{da} \int_a^{\infty} x f\left(x\right) dx=-af(a)
$$

and on the denominator 
$$
\frac{d\tilde{x}}{da}\int_a^{\infty} f\left(x\right) dx= -f(a)
$$

and then just take these two derivatives and use quotient rule to get $\frac{d\tilde{x}}{da}$

But I'm not sure if I'm applying Leibniz rule correct, in particular because Wikipedia article says there should be a  (sorry change of notation) $\int_{b(a)}^{c(a)}\frac{d}{da}f(x,a)dx$ term, but here $f$ is not a function of $a$. So is it just that $\frac{d}{da}f(x) =0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can consider $a$ as a function of $\alpha$, under some regularity condition on $f$. Then, you can apply the inverse function theorem on $a$ to compute $da / d\alpha$.
2. You have applied the Leibniz rule correctly, assuming you mean $1/ da$ instead of $d\tilde x / da$. Again, unter some regularity condition on $f$. In fact, you don't need the Leibniz rule. It is just the fundamental theorem of calculus.
3. Correct again. As both integrands do not depend on $a$, their derivatives are zero.

Concerning regularity condition on $f$: For example, it is sufficient if $f$ is continuous and positive.

Comment: Hello, and thank you. This is helpful. For 1) though, what you mean is that I can think of $\alpha$ as $\alpha(a)$ and then I know the derivative of $a(\alpha(a)) = \alpha(a)^{-1} = \frac{1}{a'(\alpha)}$? (pardon my notation at the end may not be correct)

Comment: @user106860 i meant the inverse function theorem in my answer (i corrected it). I hope it is more clear now.